# Partitions in hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, cloudera-cdh

I have dataset on CDH cluster and it is partitioned by by yyyymm.

When I run the below query on hive:

```
select actvydt, cast((concat(trim(substr(ActvyDt, 1, 4)), trim(substr(ActvyDt, 6, 2)))) as int) from pos where yyyymm=201601 and actvydt>='2016-01-01' and actvydt<='2016-01-09' limit 10;
```

It is hitting the right partition of 201601 from the dataset.

Below are the results:

```
actvydt     yyyymm
2016-01-02  201601
2016-01-02  201601
2016-01-02  201601
```

But when I run the below query: (just passing the parameter for yyyymm through subst and concat function)

```
select actvydt,cast((concat(trim(substr(ActvyDt, 1, 4)), trim(substr(ActvyDt, 6, 2)))) as int) from pos.pos_sales_weekly where yyyymm=cast(trim((concat(trim(substr(ActvyDt, 1, 4)), trim(substr(ActvyDt, 6, 2))))) as int) and actvydt>='2016-01-01' and actvydt<='2016-01-09' limit 10;
```

It is hitting the entire dataset. So the value for yyyymm is not getting passed correctly. There is some problem with this function:

```
 cast((concat(trim(substr(ActvyDt, 1, 4)), trim(substr(ActvyDt, 6, 2)))) as int)
```

But the value of the function is passed as a column and can be seen in the results above. It is showing the correct parameter 201601.
Any help would be highly appreciable.

Below is the table schema:
     `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pos (nid bigint, actvydt date, upc  string, tchid string, posfileid string, yssk bigint) PARTITIONED BY (yyyymm int) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'  LOCATION '/data/' TBLPROPERTIES ( 'avro.output.codec'='snappy' );`

Comment: If partition is `yyyymm` format why have you used `yyyymm=2016` in your first query? And in you second query you are trying to use `yyyymm=201601` from `cast` - results should not be same with these conditions. also please add table schema in question and sample data (not query results)

Comment: Sorry..that was a typo..it is 201601. Changed it..I would appreciate if you could help me on this..

Comment: is `yyyymm` defined as `string` or `int`? can you please share table schema in question.

Comment: It is Int. I have provided the schema..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition key values must be known before query execution for partition pruning to work.  You are using `WHERE` clause:  `yyyymm=cast(trim((concat(trim(substr(ActvyDt, 1, 4)), trim(substr(ActvyDt, 6, 2))))) as int) and actvydt>='2016-01-01' and actvydt<='2016-01-09'`

Optimizer unfortunately does not have such intelligence to infer `yyyymm` values from your rather complex function before query execution. Try to additionally add explicit condition: `yyyymm='201601'` This will work. You can pass it as a variable.

Comment: How to make the query work. I cant hard code it. It is based on actvydt. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Calculate  yyyymm in the shell and pass it as a hiveconf:yyyymm  parameter. Or pass min and max values as params and use ${hiveconf:min_yyyymm} > yyyymm and  yyyymm < ${hiveconf:max_yyyymm}

Comment: The query has to be run from the HUE Web UI. Is there any way to execute it from HUE.

Comment: It's possible to pass params in Hue manually. Hue cannot pre-calculate and save variables nor it can run shell. This is not acceptable probably. Try to use subquery then. `WHERE  yyyymm in (select cast(trim((concat(trim(substr(ActvyDt, 1, 4)), trim(substr(ActvyDt, 6, 2))))) as int) from default.dual) ` Hive will run subquery first, than apply filter. Partition pruning should work. Probably tou can skip `from default.dual` depending on your Hive version

Comment: I tried this:    `select actvyenddt,concat(CASE WHEN month(pos.actvyenddt) < 10
THEN concat(year(pos.actvyenddt),'0',month(pos.actvyenddt)) ELSE month(pos.actvyenddt) END)
from pos.pos_sales_weekly pos where pos.yyyymm in (select trim(concat(year('2015-01-03'),CASE WHEN month('2015-01-31') < 10 
THEN trim(concat('0',month('2015-01-31'))) ELSE month('2015-01-31') END)) from default.sample_07)
and pos.ActvyEndDt >='2015-01-03' and pos.ActvyEndDt <='2015-01-31' limit 11;`. But it throws error :

Comment: `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeConstantDesc cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeColumnDesc`

Comment: Check subquery separately, cast column it returns  to INT. It should return one column of the same type (int in your case). And I noticed you are using default.sample_07 table instead dual. This table should contain single row, because you want to return single constant. Try to remove ` from default.sample_07`. In Hive 0.14 it works without from.

Comment: `CASE` can be replaced with cast(concat(substr('2015-01-31'1,4), substr('2015-01-31',6,2)) as int)

Comment: It is not accepting constants (2015-01-31) in the subquery..If i use actvydt, then I have to go back to the same partitioned table. Moreover it is throwing error if subquery doesnt have "from clause". Using hive 1.1.0

Comment: It should accept constants in subqueries. Mine 0.14 accepts.  Try to locate a bug more carefully.  About FROM in subqueries - it's not a big problem, create any table with single row (like Oracle's DUAL table) and use it for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, somehow, the value `2016-01-01` is created.

At exactly that moment, or very close to it, you should also be able to create `201601`.

Once you do that,  you can pass it to the query in the same way as you pass `2016-01-01`, and then your problem should be solved.